# Hibernate: Is it possible to use Like and In together in Named Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, named-query

My named query is quite long because of using Like with OR as object tree is quite big. Can we use Like and In together in Named Query:

```
#Mysql
@NamedQuery(name="getDhahush", query="SELECT d.pid FROM Dhahush d WHERE lower(d.person.telephon.mobile.mobno) LIKE lower('78129%') OR lower(d.person.telephon.mobile.mobno) LIKE lower('8129%') OR lower(d.person.telephon.mobile.mobno) LIKE lower('5159%')")
```

The underlying database is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE *cannot* be used in conjuction with IN

```
e.g.
mobno LIKE IN ('781%','719%')
```

But I would remove the lower from the lower(d.person.telephon.mobile.mobno) because firstly it is a number and does not require lower and secondly and most importantly, lower() function will fail to use any index already in place on column "mobno"
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use ANY instead.

Your query becomes something like this in PostgreSQL:

```
select 'foo' like any(array['f%', '%o%', '&t']);
```

MySQL doesn't support that exact syntax but you can do something similar with a subquery:

```
select 'foo' like any( select 'f%' union select '%o%' union select '&t');
```